# Shared libraries disappear when Azure app service restarted

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an S1 Linux App Service on Azure. I need to install a shared library called libnss3.

The steps I take to install are:

1. Visit WebSSH page of app service SCM site
2. Run `apt update && apt install -y libnss3`

This correctly installs it on the app service. However if I then restart the app service, then this installation disappears, and I have to reinstall it.

What is going on here? And how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Container data (including updates) are ephemeral; they last only as long as the container is running.  Your options are:

1. Build a new, fully updated image; or
2. Build a data storage container and link your application container to it.

If you take option #2, never ever restart the data container or that content disappears too.

Most container hosting services have special dates for storage containers (sometimes called "slabs") for just this purpose.

Comment: Have I misunderstood the app service then? I simply want a server in Azure. Nothing to do with containers is needed.